# Have I done the right thing?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I ask this question here because I flagged a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16229460/450534 as *Not a real question*. But I see similar questions popup up all the time. And I figured, let me answer this one since I have come across it. I thought it important keeping in mind new developers joining the Android platform, building apps and publishing on Google Play. However, based on the number of questions being asked, quite a few of them run a risk of getting their apps removed off the Play store.

So, as mentioned above, I [answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16229710/450534). At the time of writing, it has also been accepted by the OP. But, I marked it as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/196875). Now I have read quite a lot regarding CW's, but in all honesty, I never participated in one nor have I done what I have done in this case (marking the answer Community Wiki). I also point out the reason for doing so right at the start of the question.

So the question is, was / is this the right / accepted use of marking an answer(in this case) a *Community Wiki* accepted / encouraged?

**EDIT:**

My sincerest apologies to the author of the question that I have linked to here. It got the question some attention no doubt and now the author (apparently) cannot ask questions on SO. And regardless of the merits of the votes that followed, this end result was not my intention. The context of my question here on Meta was to help me figure out if I did in fact understand the concept of CW's.

Comment: Don't worry too much. No user is question banned for a single downvoted question. And the question was bad. In fact, this same user asked the exact same question here on Meta. However, next time, when answering a bad question, perhaps improve it as well.

Comment: @Bart: That's a load off my mind. I had really started to think I was the cause. :-) And I will certainly keep the suggestion in mind. However, in this case, I doubt it could have been improved.

Comment: now can i delete that question ?

Comment: You do not want to delete that question @stackoverflow. That will only make your ban worse. And you can't delete it since it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Bart till now i am facing problem, i cant ask any question... do u have any solution for this ?

Comment: Follow the advice in the link given to you @stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

There are two main reasons to mark an answer Community Wiki:

1. You want a lower edit threshold.
2. You don't want (or you think you do not deserve) the reputation points.

The first is not often needed because (almost) anybody can suggest edits. The second is sometimes used.

In this case, I don't think you should have used the CW option. It is your answer.

Comment: If, in my view, a question is marked _Not a real question_, I don't think it is appropriate to _earn_ reputation. Technically, I am not answering it in the real sense anyway. In which case, I don't _deserve_ any potential rep either. But if you were to, hypothetically, agree to my point of view, was it appropriate to make it a CW?

Comment: Sometimes a bad question can be saved by a good answer.   And don't forget a question can be edited into a better one.

Comment: Agreed. They can be. But I am not so sure that would be the case here. Besides, the context of my answer was the ramifications later rather than a solution now. Which again makes me circle back to the original point. Since I am not offering a solution to the question, do I really deserve the rep?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe M agree with you, i knw m new then you are experts you can change my that question, but all are giving nergtive points, now m blocked, i can ask any questions on SO, now what i do, i have lot of more problems, if i cant ask then who will solve them , so kindly request donot downvote , if downvotes more then he/she cant ask any question, thanks,

Comment: till now i am facing problem, i cant ask any question... do u have any solution for this ?

Comment: @stackoverflow, if you can't ask any question, you are probably question bannen, you should have received a link with information. But I would reccommend, to edit downvoted questions and undelete/edit questions if you have deleted 2 or more.